# Http Intercepter Error in ionic 3 + Angular 5+

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using simple http intercepter class to pass jwt token to server through header.
I have written the http intercept class but when i run it shows run time error..
 do any one have implement http intercepter in ionic 3 and angular 5+..

please help

here iam attaching **app.module.ts**

```
  providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
StatusBar,HttpClient,
Push,
{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass:TokenIntercepterProvider},
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
StudentDetailsProvider,
EventServiceProvider,
EventServiceProvider,
AttendanceProvider,
GroupChatServiceProvider,
ChatserviceProvider,
RestProvider,
LocationServiceProvider,
GoogleMaps,
NativeGeocoder,
StudentparentinfoProvider,
RestusersProvider,
FcmProvider,
TokenIntercepterProvider
```

]
})

here is **tokenIntercepterProvider**

```
import {HttpClient, HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpRequest,HttpHandler,HttpEvent} from "@angular/common/http";
import  {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";


@Injectable()
export class TokenIntercepterProvider implements HttpInterceptor{
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const changedReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer xxx.xy.yyx')});
    return next.handle(changedReq);

  }

  constructor(private inj:Injector) {
    console.log('Hello TokenIntercepterProvider Provider');
  }

}
```

here iam hardcode a string to the bearer token even this is not working

the error i get when i run this

[image: error i got]

i get following error: Provider parse errors.mixing multi and no multi provider is not possible for token injection token _HTTP_INTERCEPTERS("[ERROR->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1

Comment: Please post your error as text, not as a picture.

Comment: please post you error as text with clear sense

Comment: please add multi:true

Comment: @UnluckyAj i missed that part. i think i have already added that..Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution :

Add

> {
>                 provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
>               useClass: TokenIntercepterProvider,
>               multi: true,
>             }

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    StatusBar,HttpClient,
    Push,
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass:TokenIntercepterProvider},
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    StudentDetailsProvider,
    EventServiceProvider,
    EventServiceProvider,
    AttendanceProvider,
    GroupChatServiceProvider,
    ChatserviceProvider,
    RestProvider,
    LocationServiceProvider,
    GoogleMaps,
    NativeGeocoder,
    StudentparentinfoProvider,
    RestusersProvider,
    FcmProvider,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenIntercepterProvider,
      multi: true,
    },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` in the following way:

```
{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass:TokenIntercepterProvider, multi: true},
```

The important part is the `multi: true` one.

Angular has single Dependency Injection as well as multi. Single will give you one Instance of the desired class, multi will give you an array. You cannot mix these together, either it's multi or single but with one Token you cannot mix single and multi together.

This article helps explain it a little:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 0):

```
{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass:TokenIntercepterProvider, multi: true},
```

I think I am added "multi:  true" but I miss that.

Comment: If it solved your problem please accept the solution thankyou

Comment: i Don't need to add token to all requests. When app is first installed user need to get api token from server after verifying their mobile number. so this http communication dont need the api token or at that time we don't have api token. then how did i manage this situation by using http intercepters too